# How to use limonaid to obtain LimeSurvey surveys in R?

Tags: r, json, limesurvey

I am trying to use the package `limonaid` but I always get the same error.

```r
library(limonaid)
options(lime_api = 'https://url.com/index.php/admin/remotecontrol')
options(lime_username = 'user')
options(lime_password = 'password')
get_session_key()
#> Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2.9000](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My LimeSurvey "interface" options:

[image: Lime survey interface options]

It was working with limesurvey 2.xx but since the update to the 6.xx version, it is not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Copying from my [Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/LimeSurvey/comments/179oik2/comment/k9dmw4w/?context=3) in case people here find it useful:

---

Using the Python [citric library](https://citric.readthedocs.io/), there isn't a method specifically to export responses as a Pandas data frame, and I'm hesitant to add any since I want to keep the library agnostic (e.g. the user might want to use Polars instead of Pandas, etc.).
That said, I try to document simple recipes for things just like that: https://citric.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to.html#export-responses-to-a-pandas-dataframe.

So, if you have a Python script like

```py
# export_ls_responses.py
import io
import citric
import pandas as pd
client = citric.Client("http://localhost:8001/index.php/admin/remotecontrol", "iamadmin", "secret")
data = client.export_responses(123456, file_format="csv")
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), delimiter=";", parse_dates=["datestamp", "startdate", "submitdate"], index_col="id")
```

then you can use reticulate to source this script:

```r
> library(reticulate)
> reticulate::use_virtualenv(...)
> reticulate::source_python("export_ls_responses.py")
> py$df
  submitdate lastpage startlanguage        seed     G01Q01 G01Q02 G02Q03 G02Q03[filecount]
1      [nan]      [1]        ['en'] [245240561] ['lalala']    [5]  [nan]             [nan]
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the citric library